# If $||x||=1$ and $a_1\ge a_i$. How do I prove $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 x_i^2\le a_1^2$?

Tags: inequality, optimization, vectors

If $||x||=1$ and $a_1\ge a_i$. How do I prove that $\sum^n_{i=1} a_i^2 x_i^2\le a_1^2$?
It can also be taken as a maximization problem to  maximize $\sum a_i^2x_i^2$, given the conditions.
If I put it in vector notation:

> if $x,a\in R^n$ and $x^T=[x_1,...,x_n], a^T=[a_1,...,a_n]$ such that $||x||=1$ and
> $a_1\ge a_i\ge 0$. How do I prove that $\forall x, ||a.x||\le a_1$?

I've been struggling with this for a while (not great at math). This is all I've been able to do:

To prove that $\sqrt{a_1^2x_1^2+...+a_n^2x_n^2}\le a_1$
$\Rightarrow a_1^2x_1^2+...+a_n^2x_n^2\le a_1^2$.
To make things easier let $a_i^2=b_i$ and since $||x||=1\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2=1$, let $x_i^2=y_i$
Which means I have to prove:

> $b_1y_1+...+b_ny_n\le b_1$, given $y_1+...+y_n=1$ and $b_1\ge b_i$

Intuitively it seems simple since $y_i\le 1$, and though I have not been able to refute it (taking various values), I don't know
how to prove it. I know of complex ways to prove it like using vector calculus, simplex etc., but was wondering if there was a simpler / more intuitive way.

Comment: $
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 x_i^2 \le 
\sum_{i=1}^n a_1^2 x_i^2 =
a_1^2 \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 =
a_1^2 ||x||^2 =
a_1^2
$

Comment: I was looking for something like this. Thanks.